# Finding Rows containing % symbol in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find rows that contains `'%'` symbol in a column of table.

For example, I have a column containing data as `'amylase 50% of dose'`.

How to select and filter all the rows containing `%` symbol in a given column?

Comment: You can use `col like '%[%]%'` or `charindex`

Comment: how to use charindex

Comment: you can use it like this `SELECT 1 WHERE CHARINDEX('%','afdsvds%ssdvsdd') > 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this query

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%[%]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WHERE Id LIKE '%[%]%'`. An example will be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
Id NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('100%'), ('1000')

SELECT * FROM #Test
WHERE Id LIKE '%[%]%'

DROP TABLE #Test
```

OUTPUT:

```
Id
100%
```

Answer (score 1):

We use like clause/operator to find/match anything in columns. Below query will search '%' in starting/middle/ending or can say everywhere in a column value.

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%[%]%'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%\%%'
```